Using would in a doubtful situation
I understand "would" is used when the situation is hypothetical. However, when the outcome is unknown and unsure but it is a possibility, should I use would or will is the right word?

#1 If I come to your house tomorrow, would you help me with the assignment? 
#2 If the weather is good, would the stores be open?

Is would appropriate here or should I use will?

Please go and look up conditionals. I will go if he goes. I would go if he went.

Short answer to your question is if it's uncertain but a real possibility we use 'will'.
Looking at your examples though, we have two different uses of 'would'.
#1 'would you help me' is a polite request and means 'could you help me' or 'would you mind helping me'. 'will/can' are correct, but more direct.
#2 if something happens (present tense with future aspect) will this be the case? So here we have 1st conditional.
Neither of your examples are hypothetical.
Compare, 'There's a storm warning for tomorrow, but if the weather was good, would the stores be open?' Here we have a hypothetical situation, so as you say, 'would' is the correct word.
Hope that helps.
